# How can I clear the contents of the clipboard before calling clipboard-kill-region?

Tags: clipboard

I use `clipboard-kill-region` to copy contents from Emacs to other programs. But sometimes, it copies the same content twice into the clipboard. 
It looks like,

```
/home/user/.emacs/home/user/.emacs
```

when I copy the filename

```
/home/user/.emacs
```

Is there a way I can empty the clipboard contents before calling `clipboard-kill-region`?

My complete function is shown here; it is a utility function to copy the absolute path of currently opened file in Emacs buffer:

```el
(defun sk-copy-file-name ()
  "Put the current file name on the clipboard"
  (interactive)
  (let ((filename (if (equal major-mode 'dired-mode)
                      default-directory
                    (buffer-file-name))))
    (when filename
      (with-temp-buffer
        (insert filename)
        (clipboard-kill-region (point-min) (point-max)))
      (message filename))))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `kill-new` instead of `clipboard-kill-region` for this. `clipboard-kill-region` uses `kill-region` which will append the text to the last kill if the last call was `kill-region`.

```lisp
(defun sk-copy-file-name ()
  "Put the current file name on the clipboard"
  (interactive)
  (kill-new (or (buffer-file-name) default-directory)))
```

Comment: hi Jordan, it works with emacs gui but not with emacs terminal - `emacs --no-window-system`

Comment: I believe you'll need to manually interface with the systems clipboard program, you can see how to do it on OSX here, http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10900/copy-text-from-emacs-to-os-x-clipboard