# How do I use the primary, not clipboard buffer?

Tags: evil

Aka the equivalent of `xclip -o -selection primary`, not `xclip -o -selection clipboard`. `primary` is selection, `clipboard` is `Ctrl-C` usually.

Comment: does [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10900/copy-text-from-emacs-to-os-x-clipboard) answers your question?

Comment: That's mac. xclip is specifically Linux, X11.

Comment: There are the variables `select-enable-clipboard` and `select-enable-primary`.