# Copy or paste between terminal emacs 26 and Mac apps

Tags: osx, terminal-emacs, character-encoding, emacs26

I am using terminal emacs a lot, and the method from [Copy text from Emacs to OS X clipboard](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/10900/copy-text-from-emacs-to-os-x-clipboard) works for a long time.

But after upgrading to Emacs 26, if I kill a string like "你好" from emacs, and paste here in the browser, it will be "‰Ω†Â•Ω". If I kill a string here "你好" and paste it in terminal emacs, it will be "??".

In short, the encoding is problematic.

My emacs version is: GNU Emacs 26.2 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin18.2.0, NS appkit-1671.20 Version 10.14.3 (Build 18D109)) of 2019-04-13

```lisp
(describe-coding-system)

Coding system for saving this buffer:
  Not set locally, use the default.
Default coding system (for new files):
  U -- utf-8 (alias: mule-utf-8 cp65001)

Coding system for keyboard input:
  U -- utf-8-unix (alias: mule-utf-8-unix cp65001-unix)

Coding system for terminal output:
  U -- utf-8-unix (alias: mule-utf-8-unix cp65001-unix)

Coding system for inter-client cut and paste:
  U -- utf-8-unix (alias: mule-utf-8-unix cp65001-unix)

Defaults for subprocess I/O:
  decoding: U -- utf-8-unix (alias: mule-utf-8-unix cp65001-unix)

  encoding: U -- utf-8-unix (alias: mule-utf-8-unix cp65001-unix)


Priority order for recognizing coding systems when reading files:
  1. utf-8 (alias: mule-utf-8 cp65001)
  2. iso-2022-7bit 
  3. iso-latin-1 (alias: iso-8859-1 latin-1)
  4. iso-2022-7bit-lock (alias: iso-2022-int-1)
  5. iso-2022-8bit-ss2 
  6. emacs-mule 
  7. raw-text 
  8. iso-2022-jp (alias: junet)
  9. in-is13194-devanagari (alias: devanagari)
  10. chinese-iso-8bit (alias: cn-gb-2312 euc-china euc-cn cn-gb gb2312)
  11. utf-8-auto 
  12. utf-8-with-signature 
  13. utf-16 
  14. utf-16be-with-signature (alias: utf-16-be)
  15. utf-16le-with-signature (alias: utf-16-le)
  16. utf-16be 
  17. utf-16le 
  18. japanese-shift-jis (alias: shift_jis sjis)
  19. chinese-big5 (alias: big5 cn-big5 cp950)
  20. undecided
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple.

1. for fish-shell user

```
set -x LC_ALL "en_US.UTF-8"
```

2. for bash/zsh shell user

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```