How do I write a function to copy a region to the MacOS clipboard?
I'd like to be able to mark a region in a text buffer, hit an F-key, and have the contents of the region copied into the MacOS clipboard. From the shell you can do this by piping the text into the pbcopy command, but I have no idea how to write a defun to do that. Can anyone help? I'm using GNU Emacs 29.3 installed on macOS 14.4.1 by homebrew in terminal and not a GUI.

what about (global-set-key [f2] 'kill-ring-save)?

@Saravana that doesn't export the text to the MacOS system clipboard.

Two useful answers I found:
https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/20892/2147
https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/20426/2147
I modified the second solution as follows:
(defun pbcopy ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((deactivate-mark t))
    (call-process-region (point) (mark) "pbcopy")
    (setq mark-active nil) ;; I prefer to unset region afterward
    (message "Copied"))) ;; feedback

And then,
(keymap-global-set "<f3>" 'pbcopy)

I don't have any trouble using CMD+v to paste into emacs at point, so I didn't bother to implement pbpaste.
Tested in both Terminal.app and iTerm.app.

The function is already in emacs it is clipboard-kill-ring-save -
I have bound that to cmdC where I have bound the cmd key ⌘ to super.
This does keep the kill-ring and the clipboard in sync
(setq mac-function-modifier 'hyper
        mac-option-modifier 'meta
        mac-command-modifier 'super)
; using bind-key from use-package rather than define-key
(bind-key "s-c" #'clipboard-kill-ring-save) 
(bind-key "s-x" #'clipboard-kill-region)
(bind-key "s-v" #'clipboard-yank)

There are also packages which do a similar binding but separate out the kill-ring and the OS clipboard e.g. simpleclip

Doesn't work for me: I mark out a region, Type M-x clipboard-kill-ring-save. There's a message that the command completed, and the region becomes unhighlighted. But when I switch to a different Mac application and do CMD-v, the prior contents of the Mac clipboard gets pasted.
I should note that I'm running emacs inside iterm2; i.e. not Emacs.app or similar.

That matters a lot and needs to be in your question. Basically no way then. Why not use a GUI emacs if you want to integrate with macOS

If there is a way for a defun to pipe the region text to a command (namely pbcopy), that would be enough.
